Using Google-OR Tools with OSGi and Maven
I am trying to use Google OR tools within my OSGi application.
I add the dependencies to my pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.ortools</groupId>
            <artifactId>ortools-java</artifactId>
            <version>9.11.4210</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.ortools</groupId>
            <artifactId>ortools-linux-x86-64</artifactId>
            <version>9.11.4210</version>
        </dependency>

and I wrap these in features.xml
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.ortools/ortools-java/9.11.4210</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.ortools/ortools-linux-x86-64/9.11.4210</bundle>

and also add it to app.xml
    <artifact>mvn:com.google.ortools/ortools-java/9.11.4210</artifact>
    <artifact>mvn:com.google.ortools/ortools-linux-x86-64/9.11.4210</artifact>

Now, my .oar contains both packages under m2/com/google/ortools/ and my source code under m2/my/package/path.
I load system packages and it loads without errors.
static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError exception) {
            logger.info(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

But this code throws the next error
   MPSolver solver = MPSolver.createSolver("GLOP");


java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long com.google.ortools.linearsolver.mainJNI.MPSolver_createSolver(java.lang.String)'
at com.google.ortools.linearsolver.mainJNI.MPSolver_createSolver(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at com.google.ortools.linearsolver.MPSolver.createSolver(MPSolver.java:140) ~[?:?]

How to solve this issue?
